# Find the $f^{(3)}(0)$ of $f(x) = \sin^{3}(\ln(1+x))$ using Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

For the Taylor expansions I used:

$\ln(1+x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \frac{x^{k}}{k}$

$\sin(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$

So $\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^{3}}{3!} + O(x^{5})$

and $\ln(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + O(x^4)$

Then the composite expansion (*for rest of question dropping H.O.T.*):

$\sin(\ln(1+x)) \approx (x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3}) - \frac{(x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3})^3}{3!} $

Reducing:

$\approx (x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3}) - \frac{x^3}{6} \approx x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6}$

Cube the result and simplify again:

$(x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6})^3 \approx x^3$ keeping the third-order term.

At this point, my understanding is that the coefficient of the third-order term in the formula for the general Taylor series is $f^{(3)}$

$\frac{f^{(3)}(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3$

So I believe I can infer that the coefficient of the composite Taylor expansion, 1, also relates to $f^{(3)}$, and then solving:

$\frac{f^{(3)}}{3!} = 1$

$f^{(3)} = 3! = 6$

Have I understood this question and the right approach for solving it?

Comment: Quite right..................

Comment: Another way:  $\ln (1+x)\to 0$ and $(\ln (1+x))/x\to 1$ and $(\sin x)/x \to 1$ as $x\to 0.$ So when $0<|x<1$ we have $\frac {\sin^3(\ln (1+x))}{x^3}=\frac  {\sin^3(\ln (1+x))}{\ln^3(1+x)}\cdot \frac {\ln^3(1+x)}{x^3},$ which $\to 1$ as $x\to 0.$ So $\sin^3(\ln(1+x))=x^3(1+f(x))$ where $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0,$ and $f(x)$ is analytic for $|x|<1.$ This directly implies that $(x^3(1+f(x)))'''=6$ when $x=0.$

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, though take note that you should be more careful with your remainders on each step to ensure you didn't miss anything that might contribute to the $x^3$ coefficient:

\begin{align}\sin(\ln(1+x))&=\sin\bigg(x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3+\mathcal O(x^4)\bigg)\tag{$\star$}\\&=\left[\color{#2255FF}{x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3+\mathcal O(x^4)}\right]-\frac16(\color{#228855}{x+\mathcal O(x^2)})^3+\mathcal O(\color{#FF9944}{x}^4)\\&=x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac16x^3+\mathcal O(x^4)\end{align}

$(\star)$: $\color{#2255FF}{x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3+\mathcal O(x^4)}=\color{#228855}{x+\mathcal O(x^2)}=\color{#FF9944}{\mathcal O(x)}$